# Is NativeScript Angular xml space sensitive

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have been trying out NativeScript Angular and started with the default Angular app on Windows using VSCode (that shouldn't matter). The default app has the following xml for the items component:

```
<GridLayout>
    <ListView [items]="items">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Now if I add an additional space before the terminating GridLayout tag, i.e. on last line above, the app breaks up with following message:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Calling js method run failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: ProxyViewContainer(8) CurrentParent: Page(4) ExpectedParent: AppHostView(1)
```

I could not find any documentation where it is specified that the xml must be formatted. Is this expected  behavior or is there something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know

```
</ListView>


</GridLayout>
```

this should work..!!
see if you can re-produce this error on playground and share here..